# Total amount of games not displaying at end of switch loop cycle

Tags: c++, loops, switch-statement, return-value

so for one of my projects I am supposed to give the user multiple games to choose from, which can be played however many times they would like. As soon as they exit, the program should display the total amount of games played.

I have the code for the games done, I'm just working on the menu separately. For some reason when I call for the total at the end, it doesn't output anything. Not even the initial value that I place for the integer.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int totalGames = 0;

    while (true) {

        int gameChoice;

        cout << "Which game would you like to play?\n\n";
        cin >> gameChoice;

        switch (gameChoice)
        {
            case 1 :
                cout << "You chose option 1";
                totalGames++;
            break;
            case 2 :
                cout << "You chose option 2";
                totalGames++;
            break;
            case 3 :
                cout << "You chose option 3";
                totalGames++;
            break;
            case 4 :
                return false;
            break;
            default:
                cout << "Invalid Option";    
            break;
        }

    }

    cout << "Total games: " << totalGames << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `case 4: return false;` That will terminate your program. Is that intentional?

Comment: Oh that terminates the entire program? I assumed that only terminated the switch loop cycle...

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I wasn't aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested in comment and @MichaelVeksler, case 4 exits the program and thus it doesn't output anything.
For instance, you can output it terminating while-loop using a boolean flag as follows:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Q9vn5Q2A3yYPRv0f)

```
bool doContinue = true; // flag

while (doContinue)
{
    int gameChoice;

    cout << "Which game would you like to play?\n\n";
    cin >> gameChoice;

    switch (gameChoice)
    {
        case 1 :
            cout << "You chose option 1";
            totalGames++;
        break;
        case 2 :
            cout << "You chose option 2";
            totalGames++;
        break;
        case 3 :
            cout << "You chose option 3";
            totalGames++;
        break;
        case 4 :
            doContinue = false;
        break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid Option";    
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really helpful because it actually allows me to exit the switch statement and output. Your method definitely works, but just out of curiosity is there a way to get the same result without using a boolean outside of the while loop and specifically in the switch statement?

Comment: @Jbro thx. I think that a simple way without a flag is defining a function which returns the number of games done like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ccgod7bJGhH4zhE0).

Comment: Okay cool, we're just getting into functions so I'll have to look into that more. For the time being your first answer works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with:

```
        case 4 :
            return false;
```

Which exits the program, before reaching the printing statement.